# Is it possible to get the type paramater of a typing.List at runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Say I have a `typing.List[str]` object, is it possible to get the type parameter from the type hint object at runtime? I want a field or method that would return the `str` class essentially.

Comment: It is, but not in a way that's documented or guaranteed to exist a year from now.

Comment: Runtime use of `typing` is in a pretty bad place right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging, and while not documented or official, using `__args__` works.

```
>>> Union[str, bool].__args__
(<class 'str'>, <class 'bool'>)
>>> List[str].__args__
(<class 'str'>,)
```

For some reason the union of an int and a bool is just an int, I don't dare dig any further in the mess that this module is.

```
>>> Union[int, bool]
<class 'int'>
>>> Union[bool, int]
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: `Union[int, bool]` is `int` since `bool` is a subclass of `int` (see `issubclass(bool, int)` and `help(bool)`